# How to save folder in specific folder in Google Drive

Tags: android, file-upload, google-drive-api

I can save/copy a file in any folder of Google Drive using the below code
.But when i apply this method to save the folder in any other folder, then it can't save folder, and nothing happens. I want to copy a folder and save it at another place

```
  String LocationID="0B-WFTScd2afSFS34TC-223";//getting the id of the parent folder where we have to make the new file as its child
         File orgnlFile =global_file;
         File copiedFile = new File();

        copiedFile.setTitle(orgnlFile.getTitle());       
        copiedFile.setMimeType(orgnlFile.getMimeType());
        copiedFile.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(LocationID)));
       try 
        {
            mService.files().copy(orgnlFile.getId(), copiedFile).execute();

         } catch (IOException e) 
         {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
         }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work for copy-paste folder in some other directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **copy** is duplicating the media contents of a file into a new file. Since a folder has no media contents, there is nothing to copy.

When you say "I want to copy a folder", do you mean (1) copy **only** the folder, or (2) copy the folder and all files within the folder, and do you mean (3) duplicate or simply make a second reference?

Depending on exactly what you want to achieve, the Drive API calls you need to make are different.

Perhaps the best way to explain what you want would be to express it in terms of the *nix commands "cp", "mv" and "ln"

To create a duplicate of a folder-a (which is under folder-b) and its children within folder-c, (in *nix, "cp -R /folder-b/folder-a /folder-c") you will need to :-

1. Make a new folder-a under the new parent folder (folder-c). NB although folder-a has the same name as the original. It is a different folder.
2. Make a note of the file-id of the new folder-a
3. Get a list of the children of the original folder-a (children feed)
4. For each child, copy it
5. Update the parents property of each new file to be the new folder-a

If there are folders within folder-a, you will need to do the above recursively

Comment: exactly i want copy the folder and all its files and save it in another place with the same name. please help, i will be thankful

Comment: so **copy** not **link**? I've updated my answer with the steps

Comment: thanks, i was assuming the same logic, but i was in suspection . that there might would be a direct way for this purposes.
anyway, thanks friend, you are advising me step by step, i remember your comments over my previous answer, and it was great, hope could help you in brighten your future. thumbs up for you.